# Proxy Client: unable to connect ("general SOCKS server failure")

Tags: windows, socks, proxy

Can someone help me with the following error?? Below is my log and I'm not an expert, so please explain in simple terms!

```
9/14/2015 18:30:52 PM.100 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
9/14/2015 18:30:59 PM.500 [NOTICE] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
9/14/2015 18:31:06 PM.400 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 5%: Connecting to directory server 
9/14/2015 18:31:06 PM.400 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server 
9/14/2015 18:31:07 PM.700 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 109.105.109.163:47779 ("general SOCKS server failure") 
9/14/2015 18:31:07 PM.800 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 109.105.109.163:38980 ("general SOCKS server failure") 
9/14/2015 18:31:09 PM.000 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 169.229.59.75:46328 ("general SOCKS server failure") 
9/14/2015 18:32:13 PM.200 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 83.212.101.3:80 ("general SOCKS server failure") 
9/14/2015 18:32:22 PM.900 [NOTICE] Closing no-longer-configured Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
9/14/2015 18:32:22 PM.900 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
9/14/2015 18:32:22 PM.900 [NOTICE] Closing old Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150
```

Comment: Are you using Tor or Tor Browser? Is that the complete output? Can you [edit](http://tor.stackexchange.com/posts/8668/edit) your question and add the contents of your `torrc` file if you've configured it yourself? That said are you behind firewall?

Comment: please provide your `torrc` config - so it will be clear what's going on

Comment: i have the same error and im looking for the same solution..

Answer (score 5):

Someone on your network appears to be censoring 4 out of the 5 the default obfs3 Brides that are distributed with Tor Browser. You will need to obtain a different set of Bridges from [BridgeDB](https://bridges.torproject.org), and configure Tor Browser to use them (Step 2 and Step 3 from the link, with the corresponding documentation).

Answer (score 2):

To resolve this issue,
Open Tor browser => Click on **Configure** button => select **Tor is censored in my country** option => Click on **Request a new Bridge** => enter captcha then click **Submit**.

you will get a Bridge as shown in below image.

[image: Tor Network Settings screenshot]

Still, you face connection failure issue try Requesting a new Bridge as mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your ISP might be blocking Tor, using DPI (*Deep Packet Inspection*). Try using Pluggable Transports. You can download it here: https://www.torproject.org/docs/pluggable-transports.html.en#download

Here is a great tutorial on how to set it up: https://fteproxy.org/help-client-with-tor

> Note: You need to download Pluggable Transports, only if you, for some
>   reasons, are using older versions of TOR. In the latest bundles its
>   already inside.

Comment: Note that the ISP doesn't necessarily have to use DPI to know that the OP is using Tor. The ISP may just know the IP addresses of the entry nodes/bridges that the OP is trying to use.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what [Yawning Angel](https://tor.stackexchange.com/users/78/yawning-angel) already wrote:
You should select a pluggable transport like [obfs4 from BridgeDB](https://bridges.torproject.org/bridges?transport=obfs4). This method is quite censor-ship resistant and often not blocked.

Besides from visiting the website you can also write a mail to bridges@torproject.org from a RiseUp, GMail or Yahoo! address with the subject *get transport obfs4*. The BridgeDB will send you some bridge addresses.

Within the Tor browser you click on the green onion and select the Tor network settings. When you check "My ISP blocks connections …" a submenu will open and you can paste the bridge lines there. Tor Browser will try to use the pluggable transport and you are able to use the net again.