# am failing to connect to tor and below is my log. i have tried using the meek brdges but nothing seems to work. i need help

Tags: error, connection

```
8/20/19, 03:47:00.192 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
8/20/19, 03:54:51.291 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
8/20/19, 03:54:51.291 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
8/20/19, 03:54:51.291 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
8/20/19, 03:54:51.291 [NOTICE] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
8/20/19, 03:54:51.291 [NOTICE] Opened Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
8/20/19, 03:54:56.236 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 5%: Connecting to directory server 
8/20/19, 03:54:56.237 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server 
8/20/19, 03:55:56.297 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server. (DONE; DONE; count 1; recommendation warn; host 97700DFE9F483596DDA6264C4D7DF7641E1E39CE at 0.0.2.0:2) 
8/20/19, 03:55:56.298 [WARN] 1 connections have failed: 
8/20/19, 03:55:56.298 [WARN] 1 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv2/v3 read server hello A in HANDSHAKE 
8/20/19, 03:55:56.316 [NOTICE] Closing no-longer-configured Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
8/20/19, 03:55:56.316 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections.
```

Comment: This looks to be a duplicate of https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/8668/proxy-client-unable-to-connect-general-socks-server-failure.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Proxy Client: unable to connect ("general SOCKS server failure")](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/8668/proxy-client-unable-to-connect-general-socks-server-failure)